# Modularized design question using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am looking for an advice on the design decision. I want to create a reusable module(s) include aspx pages. Let’s say I have a huge project which has 10 different modules. When I built the modules all of the modules are built with its own business logic and data access layer. But the UI (.aspx/.ascx) is in one single project. I want to have UI also to be separated and put in the same project related to that module.

Here is the scenario, let’s say, I have created a news feed reader module for twitter, which has

NewsReaderBO – Business Layer (could be in web service)
NewsReaderDAL – Data access Layer
I want to create a NewsReaderUI project where the related UI is placed in such a way it should be easy to plug into other projects.

The advice I am looking for is how the main container project should be designed/organized/architected so that integration of these sub projects is easy.

Are there any references available for this scenario?

The challenge is, over my experience I have worked on various modules now it so happened that when I am creating a new site. I am copying the code from each one, whereby I end up having so many copies of the same thing.

Any advice on this?

Regards
Sai

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a webforms application you could put each module into it's own library.  In the library you could put your code for the module and implement the UI for the module as a server control instead of apspx or ascx, and then use those in pages pages in your main project.